# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом ИЛИ?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, спп, или

*Если в данный момент учащийся не занят в свободное время, то напишите, где занимался раньше или где хотел бы заниматься.*

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не ставится: **Если в данный момент учащийся не занят в свободное время, то напишите, где занимался раньше или где хотел бы заниматься.**

[Лопатин. Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134)

Правило:

2. Между двумя придаточными, соединенными одиночными соединительными или разделительными союзами **и, или, либо, да** (в значении «и»), запятая не ставится (при этом подчинительный союз или союзное слово может и не повторяться):

   Точь-в-точь такую же жалость вызывала у нее и мать, Зинаида Витальевна, **когда**, забыв про своих продавщиц, парикмахерш и массажисток, усталая, укладывалась на ночлег **или** **когда** учила девочку завязывать бантики (Бел.) — две придаточные части времени, соединенные союзом или.